# Currency class only one instance per currency?

Tags: java, format, currency

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html) official oracle java tutorial:

> Note that the Currency class is designed so that there is never more
>   than one Currency instance for any given currency. Therefore, there is
>   no public constructor. As demonstrated in the previous code example,
>   you obtain a Currency instance using the getInstance methods.

What is the risk of having more than one instance of Currency for a given currency?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: the risk is that you modify a property on one instance, while using another instance that doesn't know about the change.

Comment: @njzk2 could you please provide me with an example of such a modification?

Comment: read about singleton pattern

Comment: @njzk2 You said "the risk is that you modify a property on one instance", I replied "please show me an example of such a modification".. The thing is that it's not possible to modify even the single instance. Check out the BMT answer, apparently it is a design choice which yes it will use a singleton for each ISO

Answer (score 0):

Refer link [Currency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html)

> Representation of a currency for a particular locale.  Each currency
>   is identified by its ISO 4217 code, and only one instance of this
>   class exists per currency.  As a result, instances are created
>   via the `getInstance()` methods rather than by using
>   a constructor.

As [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html) says you can supersede the Java runtime currency data by creating a properties file named `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/currency.properties`. The contents of the properties file are key/value pairs of the ISO 3166 country codes and the ISO 4217 currency data respectively. The value part consists of three ISO 4217 values of a currency, i.e., an alphabetic code, a numeric code, and a minor unit. Those three ISO 4217 values are separated by commas. The lines which start with '#'s are considered comment lines. For example,

**Sample currency properties**

JP=JPZ,999,0

will supersede the currency data for Japan.

Comment: So it is more a design consistency/cohesion kind of thing rather than functional thing?

Comment: yes,  you can not update it through instance but see updated answer.